# How to run fpg algorithm of mahout on hortonworks?

Tags: mahout, bigdata

I utilized hortonworks to run job of big data. 
How to run the fpg-growth algorithm of mahout on hortonworks?
Please, Anyone introduce.

Answer (score 0):

Mahout is deprecated. Try Spark MLlib
;-)